# iOS pass search query into Mail

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, ios7

I'm making an iOS app where e-mail is used to send data files from patient to clinician (and vice versa).  I've set up the Info.plist to be able to open e-mails of the specified type with my app as well as a MFMailComposeViewController to automatically generate an e-mail with specified files attached.

What I am wondering is if it is possible to link to the Mail client and pass in a search query so that clicking a button in my app opens up the Mail client and begins a search for messages from a specified sender?  I've seen that you can link to a specific message in Mail by using message:message-id where message-id is the URL-encoded value of the “Message-ID” (see https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/6c212bc79bd9) but 1) I won't know the message-ID and 2) I want to list more than 1 e-mail.

Anybody ever tried this or know if it's possible?

Comment: No, nothing like this is currently available in iOS.